# Turn off MOSFET after delay

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I have a circuit using a PWM signal from a microcontroller to control the gate of a P-channel MOSFET in order to generate a higher voltage PWM. The device being controlled by this PWM signal turns off with logic high and turns on with logic low or if left floating. This is already on the PCB and is not easy to modify. Below is the circuit:

[image]

It is working fine but the problem is at the start-up. When the system is first turned on, I need the PWM signal high so that the device is initially off for a brief moment, maybe half a second, until the MCU is ready to take control of the signal. With the current configuration, the output is low.

I try adding another P-channel in parallel to it, so that I don't have to modify the original circuit. The intention is to have it pull the signal high, and then after a delay, C2 charges up, turns on the PNP, which disconnects this additional P-channel from the circuit. However, in the simulation, the output is always 48V.

[image]

Could anyone please point out where I did wrong?

Comment: *The device being controlled by this PWM signal turns off with logic high and turns on with logic low or if left floating* Not sure I understand- If the signal labeled "MCU" is high, M2 turns on and the load, presumably R47 is on.  Is that the intended operation?

Comment: @JohnD yes that is correct.

Comment: How are you able to add components when you say "This is already on the PCB and is not easy to modify" and later you say "I try adding another P-channel in parallel to it, so that I don't have to modify the original circuit." So can you you modify the PCB or you can't?

Comment: @MOSFET I can make another circuit on a breadboard and solder jumpers to the output of on the existing PCB.

Comment: "The device being controlled by this PWM signal turns off with logic high and turns on with logic low or if left floating."  Are you sure?  I think it would be reversed: when MCU is low or floating, Q1 is off which turns M2 off.  M2 can only turn on when Q1 is on, which requires MCU output to be high.  Please confirm or correct my understanding.

Comment: You must clamp the gate voltage of M2 to <15 V.

Comment: @FabioBarone Sorry if I made it confusing. By logic high and logic low, I meant the 48V output. Logic high means M2 conducted and the load sees 48V. Logic low is when M2 open-circuited.

Comment: @winny I will add a Zener between gate and source. But wouldn't the voltage divider formed by R39 and R43  keep Vgs at around -15V?

Comment: @HV16  I still don't understand the problem.  The circuit as-is operates as follows **at start-up**, assuming the voltage "MCU" = 0V or is floating: Q1 is OFF & M2 is OFF (open), and the voltage at R47 is 0V.   For M2 to turn ON (close) requires that voltage "MCU" must go "high" (+5V).   In other words: output voltage (at R47) stays low until you set "MCU" to be "high".  Isn't this what you want the circuit to do?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Do you have any corner case where the 48 V is low, during startup or shutdown? If yes, increasing R43 and placing a Zener diode in parallel will soak up that difference.

Answer (score 1):

Through a signal diode, add a capacitor from the Q1 collector to GND, and a resistor from the cap to the +48.  This will hold the M2 (upper schematic) gate low while the capacitor charges up.

UPDATE2:  Here is a second-pass **concept** schematic.  It is a reduced version of the first schematic in the question, with a turn-off timer added.

[image]

When power is applied, C1 starts charging through R43, R39, D1, and R1.  The time constant is approx. 0.16 s, so three time constants (95% charge) is a little under 0.5 s.  Depending on the specific FET, this is approximately when it will begin turning off.  Adjust R1 for the desired ON time.

After M2 turns off, C1 keeps charging up to Vcc through R1, reverse-biasing D1  This disconnects the timing circuit from the PWM drive circuit.

Comment: I appreciate the schematic and the explanation. One question: when the power is removed, how is C1 discharged, so that the next time power is applied, this whole process can be repeated?

Comment: Another 33K resistor, from the +48 rail to GND, dissipates less than 0.1 W continuously, and will discharge C1, through R1, to 1% of full charge in 3.3 seconds.

Comment: Should I add this resistor in parallel with C1 so that it discharges faster as it doesn't have to go through R1?

Comment: No.  That would form a voltage divider with R1, preventing the diode from becoming reverse-biased.  The FET never would turn off.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following circuit which should fullfill the requirements.
C1/R7 adds a delay to have the output high. D1 is necessary to not fry M3.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sorry, I should have mentioned that the control circuit is already on the PCB and it would not be easy to modify. I will add this to the question. I was looking to do this with another circuit where I could tie it in parallel to the output.

Comment: Please correct me if I misunderstand the circuit. So initially at power on, Q3 conducts, Vgs of M3 is 15V because of the zener D1 and R8. C1 starts charging through R7 to 48V. When C1 is at 48V, the base and emitter of Q3 are both 48V thus turn off Q3 and disconnect M3 from the output.

Comment: But at power off, how will C1 be discharged?

Comment: @HV16 yes you are correct about the circuit. 
At power off, I assume it is discharged through V1.